# Marginal Means accounting for the random effect uncertainty

Tags: mixed-models

When we have repeated measurements on an experimental unit, typically these units cannot be considered 'independent' and need to be modeled in a way that we get valid estimates for our standard errors.

When I compare the intervals obtained by computing the marginal means for the treatment using a mixed model (treating the unit as a random effect) and in the other case, first averaging over the unit and THEN runnning a simple linear model on the averaged responses, I get the exact same uncertainty intervals.

How do we incorporate the uncertainty of the measurements of the unit, into the uncertainty of what we think our treatments look like?

In order to really propogate all the uncertainty, shouldn't we see what the treatment looks like, averaged over "all possible measurements" on a unit?

````r
``` r

    library(dplyr) 
    #> 
    #> Attaching package: 'dplyr'
    #> The following objects are masked from 'package:stats':
    #> 
    #>     filter, lag
    #> The following objects are masked from 'package:base':
    #> 
    #>     intersect, setdiff, setequal, union
    library(emmeans) 
    library(lme4) 
    #> Loading required package: Matrix
    library(ggplot2)
    
    tmp <- structure(list(treatment = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
    "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
    "B", "B", "B", "B"), response = c(151.27333548, 162.3933313, 
    159.2199999, 159.16666725, 210.82, 204.18666667, 196.97333333, 
    194.54666667, 154.18666667, 194.99333333, 193.48, 191.71333333, 
    124.1, 109.32666667, 105.32, 102.22, 110.83333333, 114.66666667, 
    110.54, 107.82, 105.62000069, 79.79999821, 77.58666557, 75.78666928
    ), experimental_unit = c("A-1", "A-1", "A-1", "A-1", "A-2", "A-2", 
    "A-2", "A-2", "A-3", "A-3", "A-3", "A-3", "B-1", "B-1", "B-1", 
    "B-1", "B-2", "B-2", "B-2", "B-2", "B-3", "B-3", "B-3", "B-3"
    )), row.names = c(NA, -24L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
    ))
    
    
    ### Option 1 - Treat the experimental unit as a random effect since there are 
    ### 4 repeat observations for the same unit  
    
    lme4::lmer(response ~ treatment + (1 | experimental_unit), data = tmp) %>% 
      emmeans::emmeans(., ~ treatment) %>% 
      as.data.frame() 
    #>   treatment   emmean       SE df  lower.CL upper.CL
    #> 1         A 181.0794 10.83359  4 151.00058 211.1583
    #> 2         B 101.9683 10.83359  4  71.88947 132.0472
      #ggplot(.,aes(treatment, emmean)) + 
      #geom_pointrange(aes(ymin = lower.CL, ymax = upper.CL))  
    
    
    
    
    
    ### Option 2 - instead of treating the unit as random effect, we average over the 
    ### 4 repeat observations, and run a simple linear model  
    
    tmp %>%
      group_by(experimental_unit) %>%
      summarise(mean_response = mean(response)) %>%
      mutate(treatment = c(rep("A", 3), rep("B", 3))) %>%
      lm(mean_response ~ treatment, data = .) %>%
      emmeans::emmeans(., ~ treatment) %>%
      as.data.frame() 
    #>   treatment   emmean       SE df  lower.CL upper.CL
    #> 1         A 181.0794 10.83359  4 151.00058 211.1583
    #> 2         B 101.9683 10.83359  4  71.88947 132.0472
      #ggplot(., aes(treatment, emmean)) +
      #geom_pointrange(aes(ymin = lower.CL, ymax = upper.CL))  
    
    
    
    
    ### Whether we include a random effect for the unit, or average over it and THEN model it, we find no difference in the 
    ### marginal means for the treatments 
    
    ### How do we incoporate the variation of the repeat measurments to the marginal means of the treatments? 
    ### Do we then ignore the variation in the 'subsamples' and simply average over them PRIOR to modeling? 
    
    
    <sup>Created on 2021-07-31 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.0)</sup>
````

Answer (score 0):

`emmeans()` *does* take into account the errors of random effects. This is what I get when I remove the complex sequences of pipes:

```
> mmod = lme4::lmer(response ~ treatment + (1 | experimental_unit), data = tmp)
> emmeans(mmod, "treatment")
 treatment emmean   SE df lower.CL upper.CL
 A            181 10.8  4    151.0      211
 B            102 10.8  4     71.9      132

Degrees-of-freedom method: kenward-roger 
Confidence level used: 0.95
```

This is as shown. If I fit a fixed-effects model that accounts for experimental units as a fixed effect, I get:

```
> fmod = lm(response ~ treatment + experimental_unit, data = tmp)
> emmeans(fmod, "treatment")
NOTE: A nesting structure was detected in the fitted model:
    experimental_unit %in% treatment
 treatment emmean   SE df lower.CL upper.CL
 A            181 3.25 18    174.2      188
 B            102 3.25 18     95.1      109

Results are averaged over the levels of: experimental_unit 
Confidence level used: 0.95
```

The SEs of the latter results are considerably lower, and that is because the random variations in `experimental_unit` are modeled as fixed variations.

Apparently the piping you did accounts for the variation of the random effects and includes those in the EMMs. I think that is because you did things separately for each experimental unit and somehow combined those results. I'm not very comfortable with a sequence of pipes that is 7 steps long, and I don't understand why that results in just one set of means.

I recommend against the `as.data.frame()` at the end. That zaps out annotations that can be helpful in understanding what you have. If you are doing that to get more digits precision, I'll claim that those are digits you don't need, it just exaggerates the precision you are entitled to claim.

### Notes on some follow-up comments

Subsequently, I am convinced that what we see in the piped operations in the second part of the OP doe indeed comprise computing the mean of each EU, then analyzing those.

Let's look at that in the context of the formal model. We have (sorry MathJax doesn't work on stackoverflow, but I'll leave the markup there anyway)

$$ Y_{ijk} = \mu + \tau_i + U_{ij} + E_{ijk} $$

where $Y_{ijk}$ is the kth response measurement on the ith treatment and jth EU in the ith treatment, and the rhs terms represent respectively the overall mean, the (fixed) treatment effects, the (random) EU effects, and the (random) error effects. We assume the random effects are all mutually independent. With a balanced design, the EMMs are just the marginal means:

$$ \bar Y_{i..} = \mu + \tau_i + \bar U_{i.} + \bar E_{i..} $$

where a '.' subscript means we averaged over that subscript. If there are n EUs per treatment and m measurements on each EU, we get that

$$ Var(\bar Y_{i..} = \sigma^2_U / n + \sigma^2_E / mn $$

Now, if we aggregate the data on EUs ahead of time, we are starting with

$$ \bar Y_{ij.} = \mu + U_{ij} + \bar E_{ij.} $$

However, if we then compute marginal means by averaging over j, we get exactly the same thing as we did before with $\bar Y_{i..}$, and the variance is exactly as already shown. That is why it doesn't matter if we aggregated first or not.

Comment: And BTW if you do want all those undeserved extra digits, you can do `emm_options(opt.digits = FALSE)` just after you load the package.

Comment: I think those pipes takes the means of the experimental units and then uses them in a linear model. A disaggregated repeated measures model and an aggregated model of means should give the same fixed effects estimates and SEs on balanced data, no? (I don’t have a reference handy to check though.)

Comment: Yes, that makes sense when you have a nested structure.

Comment: In fact the data need not be balanced, except that the sizes of the nests must be balanced ed. You could have different number of nests in each treatment.

Comment: Thank you both! Yes Russ, in the 2nd I'm avging over the data and then running a simple lm without the unit as a RE. I was under the impression that when we include a repeated measured unit as a random effect, we propogate that uncertainty to the FE - but it seems with balanced data, it doesn't really matter. I'm still confused what situations we would want to propogate the uncertainty of the REs. Ben shows here how, if we did want to, include the error of the REs into the FE intervals. But are these prediction intervals now?! http://bbolker.github.io/mixedmodels-misc/glmmFAQ.html#lme4

Comment: By averaging over each EU, you are masking the WITHIN-EU variations. It is the between-EU variations that remain, and in your particular situation, are exactly correct for evaluating treatment means. As I said, `emmeans()` *does* incorporate the needed random-effect variations. Look at https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/sophisticated.html#lmer, for example, and note that the contrasts for the split-plot factor have a much smaller variance than those for the whole-plot factor; and also that some of the whole-plot variations cancel out when computing split-plot contrasts.

Comment: Yes, I think Ben is computing prediction intervals in those wider intervals. It's possible to do that with **emmeans** too. See https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/emmeans/vignettes/predictions.html . With `lmer` models, you need to calculate tge total SD from `VarCorr()` results.

Comment: Hi Russ - I absolutely agree with you. emmeans does correct for the within EU variation. However, if we average out the date prior to modeling, we get the same intervals as if we model the EU variation and then average over the RE. Notice in the 2nd model there is no EU term - just FE for treatment. My confusion is maybe borderline stats philosophy - not an emmeans thing! I absolutely love the package.  I always thought the RE uncertainty propogated to the FE uncertainty, but if we average out the RE units prior, it gives us the same answer.

Comment: See my amended answer which explains why it works that way. I wish somebody else would support my vote to close and migrate this to CrossValidated (which is where it should have been anyway), where the math will look a lot more readable.

Comment: @user3536311 Was my answer of use? If so, I'd appreciate your accepting it or upvoting it